# Can we emit vertices in between when in where clause

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I wish to traverse in a unidirectional way but facing difficulty in going back and fetching the vertex which is filtered in path . Please help.

```
g.V().hasLabel('states').as('s').
  in().hasLabel('url').as('u').
  select('s').
  where(and(inE('exporting').has('forward','states'),
            inE('release').has('forward','states'))).
  select('u')
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? The traversal looks fine to me, although it contains a few unnecessary steps.

Comment: Thanks for formatting . On running this query it is returning the 'u' variable vertices but , what I want is filtered vertices . That is on running the where clause it should come back and fetch only those 'u' vertices which are filtered using where on path and not all.

Comment: That should be the case. But let me simplify your query, maybe that'll help.

Answer (score 1):

Since all your filters pretty much depend on `s`, it makes sense to use `match()` step.

```
g.V().hasLabel('states').
  match(__.as('s').in().hasLabel('url').as('u'),
        __.as('s').inE('exporting').has('forward','states'),
        __.as('s').inE('release').has('forward','states')).
  select('u')
```

That, at least, makes it easier to read. However, there's an even simpler way to write your query, which requires no labels at all:

```
g.V().hasLabel('states').
  and(inE('exporting').has('forward','states'),
      inE('release').has('forward','states')).
  in().hasLabel('url')
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not giving me filtered url. It is actually fetching all the url vertices which are tied with states label. I wish to retrieve the url vertices  going back the filtered path

Comment: That's what it does. Maybe provide a small sample graph and show the expected result to explain what you need.